# If this character does not return to their timeline, won't it cause problems?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

As mentioned by the Ancient One in *Avengers: Endgame*, if you don't return to the exact moment it would affect reality, so shouldn't Gamora from 2014 return not to affect the reality/timeline?

Comment: That's not what was said. She was clearly talking about the stones.

Comment: I already watched 4 times dude.. it's just if the missing stone can create alternate timeline. Possibly missing person may led to creation of an altenate timeline

Comment: Gamora could return to attempt to limit the affect, but with the death of Thanos, his other children, and an army, the changes are unavoidable at this point. That timeline is different and that can't be undone now. However, not returning the Time Stone has proven downsides for reality, while destroying Thanos might actually help that reality. So there's at least hope that the timeline was disrupted for the better

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What the Ancient One was saying is that if the **stone** is **removed** from the timeline and never replaced, then that reality branches off and creates another reality where that stone doesn't exist. She visualizes this to Bruce by the golden string that branches off with a black string. If the stones are taken from a point in time, but then put back at the exact same time then nothing changes. That is why there was such a focus on returning the stones to their original timelines. This is what Hope and Scott were trying to get the van up and running for, and it's what Steve Rogers does at the end of the movie.

Now, 2014 Gamora, 2014 Nebula and 2014 Thanos have left their timeline, so theoretically the reality they were from has branched off into a reality where they no longer exist, but we don't see this. We don't really learn enough from the movie to know what this means, but it's not important for us as it's not in the reality/timeline that we saw.

Comment: While we don't see it, it is clear that 2014-Nebula inadvertently saved the whole 2014-universe from the snap by enabling 2014-Thanos to leave that timeline (and be defeated in our timeline).